# Functional programming with nested promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, functional-programming, promise

In an Angular project, I'm working on a booking system with a lot of different scenarios. Based on the response of a promise, it should try to make a different call to the server. This results in a sort of callback-hell of which I thought promises can prevent me from: functions don't return anything but initiate another function.

Here is a simplified decision tree:

- 1. Make booking

     - 1.1 (succes) - Fetch booking details

       - 1.1.1 (success) - Show booking details to user
       - 1.1.2 (fail) - Show retry button
     - 1.2 (fail) - Check errorCode

       - 1.2.1 if (errorCode === 'soldout')

         - 1.2.1.1 - Try make alternative booking
         - 1.2.1.1.1 (succes) Load booking details
         - 1.2.1.1.1.1 (succces) CheckPriceDifference()
         - 1.2.1.1.1.2 (fail) Show soldOutMessage();
     - 1.2.2 if (errorCode != 'soldout')
           * Show retry button.

My code looks something like this:

```
makeBooking()
.then(function(response){
     succesHandler(response);
}, function(error){
    errorHandler(response);
})

succesHandler(response){
    loadDetails(response)
      .then(function(details){
          showDetails(details);
    }, function(error){
          handleDetailsError(error);
    }
 }

 errorHandler(response){
     if ( checkSoldout(reponse) ){
          makeAlternativeBooking();
     }
 }
```

Is this a good (function) way to work with these 'nested' promises?

Comment: I wouldn't blame this on promises, your logic is just a bit involved

Comment: Always return from a Promise handler. Else the promise resulting from `makeBooking()` would not wait for the result from either the successHandler or errorHandler to resolve/reject itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your flow diverges at each point, not much changes can be done to your code, except, it can be shortened slightly like:

```
makeBooking().then(succesHandler, errorHandler)

succesHandler(response){
    loadDetails(response)
      .then(showDetails, handleDetailsError)
 }

 errorHandler(response){
     if ( checkSoldout(reponse) ){
          makeAlternativeBooking();
     }
 }
```